fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature with Renderer=HarfBuzz or Renderer=OpenType
With Renderer=Node, I can use fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature to create custom features. With Renderer=HarfBuzz or Renderer=OpenType, I cannot. Should I be able to? Is there another way to do it?
The MWE is based on the example on page 57 of fontspec.pdf. The Vollkorn font is available on GitHub.
(I’m using Vollkorn version 5.000 that has changed the feature data. Of course I could simply use the ss11 feature directly, but I’m trying to solve the general problem of custom features for other fonts.)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
    fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
        name = "onealt",
            type = "substitution",
            data = {
            ["one"] = "one.ss11",
            ["one.tosf"] = "one.tosf.ss11",
        }
    }
}
\newfontfamily\node    {Vollkorn-Regular.ttf}[RawFeature=+onealt,Renderer=Node]
\newfontfamily\harfbuzz{Vollkorn-Regular.ttf}[RawFeature=+onealt,Renderer=HarfBuzz]
\newfontfamily\opentype{Vollkorn-Regular.ttf}[RawFeature=+onealt,Renderer=OpenType]
\begin{document}
\Huge
{\node     1 \small [Node]}\par
{\harfbuzz 1 \small [HarfBuzz]}\par
{\opentype 1 \small [OpenType]}\par
\end{document}


